# screen: Move to next screen on close

Tags: gnu-screen

Im often using the screen-tool to open several shells and then switch between them by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

The thing is, whenever I close a window (regardless of using "exit" in the shell, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or anything else) I always get moved back to the last window I had open before switching.
Is there a way to tell screen, to bring me to the **next** shell in the line, instead?

Comment: Are you satisfied with number9's answer? If so, can you chose it? If not, can you tell us what you are expecting?

Answer (score 4):

This seems pretty useful, however, you want to bind a key to two commands... The solution to that was found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111211/bind-more-than-one-command-to-single-key-in-screen).

The answer is to use eval, so in your `.screenrc` insert the following (as an example, you can change the binding to your liking):

```
bind k eval "next" "prev" "kill"
```

User xhienne also observes that you do not need quotes when using Control-A, as such:

```
bind k eval next prev kill
```

You are binding the three commands next, prev and kill to the letter k (so you hit control-a then k). At first I thought I solved the problem with bind k kill next, but after some testing it became apparent that it was in fact doing as the [manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Kill) (which is to fall back to the previously *displayed* window, not the previous or next window)

This answer updated as per xhienne observations (which are correct) below. They note that since it displays the previously *displayed* you need to go to the next window, then previous, then kill that window in order to get the posters desired behavior.

Comment: Interesting solution. The problem with `bind k eval kill next` is that `screen` switches to the terminal that follows the _previous_ terminal. Suppose you have 4 terminals, you switch to term #1 then to term #3: the OP want term #4 to appear when term #3 is closed, whereas your solution switches to term #2 (next to previous term #1). I think that what the OP wants is `bind k eval next prev kill` instead.

Comment: Indeed. Screens kill always switches back to the previously displayed (gee, I should have read my own notes). I put: bind k eval "next" "prev" "kill" and it works fine. Note on my .screenrc, the " " are necessary.

Comment: I tested live with `ctrl-A :`, that's probably why I didn't need the quotes. Can you update your answer with my (properly quoted) suggestion? Or I can do it if you prefer.

Comment: I have updated my response above. Thank you.